# MySQL query for 2 tables and make new column from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables. You can check this link for the tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feb71/1

I also got this query:

```
SELECT convID,Member1,Member2 
FROM tb_conversation WHERE Member1 = '1008' OR Member2 = '1008'
```

The first query is for table `tb_conversation` to make a new column that will have the record of the column that has not the id of the member 1008.

Example

```
| CONVID | MEMBER1 | MEMBER2 | newColumn |
|    1   |   1008  |   1017  |    1017   |
```

The second query is to join the 2 tables and check if is there a relation between those 2 members (to have relation there are 2 records 1 is `fromID = 1008` to `toID = 1017` with `relStatus = 1` and the other records is `fromID = 1017` to `toID = 1008` with `relStatus` 1)

Actually I need to get the members that I have in my friend list (and a conversation exist) and the members that I don't have in my friend list (and a conversation exist).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select tb0.*, tm0.relStatus from tb_conversation tb0 join
  tb_member_relation tm0 on 
    tm0.fromID = tb0.Member1 or
    tm0.toID = tb0.Member1 or
    tm0.fromID = tb0.Member2 or
    tm0.toID = tb0.Member2
  where tm0.fromID = 1008 or tm0.toID = 1008;
```

This *should* get you the conversations where 1008 is involved.

**but**

if you alter your table structure to eliminate the need for 'from' and 'to' and just use ends of a conversation you could simplify this a great deal.

Comment: That's a good point for your comments. I will make the changes.
Thank you